# Compute the fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let X be the quotient of $S^1 \times [0,1]$ by the identification $(x,y) \sim (e^{2\pi i/3}x,y), y \in \{0,1\}$. Isn't it just a rotation of the cylinder's top and bottom by the same degree? Shouldn't the fundamental group just be the fundamental group of the cylinder?

Edit: It shouldn't be the fundamental group of the cylinder since it is not the rotation. It identifies every three points on the top and bottom circle of the cylinder.

Comment: For every point in the circle, you are gluing two other points to it, and leaving the interval alone, if I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: Yes, do you know how to calculate its fundamental group? @AlfredYerger

Comment: Fundamental group of a product is product of the groups, which is just Z. Now you're taking a quotient. Based on the equivalence relation, I suspect it's the group of order 3, but I don't have a proof immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Seifert-van Kampen on the pair of open sets $U = S^1\times[0,1)/{\sim}$ and $V = S^1\times(0,1]/{\sim}$ which each deformation retract onto a circle, but whose intersection has a generator of $\pi_1$ that gets mapped to $3$ times a generator under the inclusion into either of these subspaces. I leave the details to you.

Comment: so we have $\pi_1(X)=\langle a,b|a^3=b^3\rangle\ne\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Can you explain why does each $U$ and $V$ retract to the circle? They are identified, shouldn't them be different from the circle?